# How to enable space reclamation from KVM guest to ZFS zvol iSCSI target?

Tags: zfs, iscsi, disk-space-utilization, scsi, thin-provisioning

I have a ZFS volume "tank/kvm/webhosting", exposed through iSCSI (using `tgt`) to KVM guest.

```
<disk type='block' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native' discard='unmap'/>
      <source dev='/dev/disk/by-path/ip-10.1.200.2:3260-iscsi-iqn.2016-05.bla:webhosting-lun-1'/>
      <target dev='sda' bus='scsi'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
```

How to enable space reclamation on ZFS? From guests side it's working (`fstrim -v /`), but iSCSI/ZFS host shows errors in log:

```
tgtd[324]: tgtd: bs_rdwr_request(227) Failed to punch hole for WRITE_SAME command
tgtd[324]: tgtd: bs_rdwr_request(370) io error 0x18086b0 93 -1 0 2674021892096, No such device
```

Property `Thin-provisioning: Yes` is set on LUN.